# Prolog ERROR: Undefined procedure, <= involved

Tags: prolog

I am working on a program in prolog, and am stuck with the following issue: I have defined the predicate neighbors(+,+,+,+,?) like this:

```
neighbors(X, Y, Height, Width, Neighbors):-
   Xup is X-1,
   Xdown is X+1,
   Yleft is Y-1,
   Yright is Y+1,
   findall((A,B,C),(
            between(Xup, Xdown, A),
            between(Yleft, Yright, B),
            A>=1,
            B>=1),
            Neighbors).
```

Now the query neighbors(5,5,5,5,X) works as expected, unifying X with a list of it's neighbors, namely

```
X = [ (4, 4, _G2809), (4, 5, _G2800), (4, 6, _G2791), (5, 4, _G2782), (5, 5, _G2773), (5, 6, _G2764), (6, 4, _G2755), (6, ..., ...), (..., ...)] .
```

However a problem arises when I try to add the following lines to my findall Goal:

```
A<=Height,
B<=Width
```

the full predicate looks like this:

```
neighbors(X, Y, Height, Width, Neighbors):-
   Xup is X-1,
   Xdown is X+1,
   Yleft is Y-1,
   Yright is Y+1,
   findall((A,B,C),(
            between(Xup, Xdown, A),
            between(Yleft, Yright, B),
            A>=1,
            B>=1,
            A<=Height,
            B<=Width
            ),
            Neighbors).
```

Now the same query, neighbors(5,5,5,5,X). results in me getting the following error:

```
ERROR: Undefined procedure: neighbors/5
ERROR:     However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         neighbor/2
ERROR:         neighbors/2
false.
```

What could be the reason? I imagine it's got to do with the way I'm comparing those variables, but since Width and Height are instantiated I thought that should work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your comparison operators. The syntax for the less than or equal to operator is `=</2`. So your goals should be:

```
...
A=<Height,
B=<Width
...
```

Comment: It's actually the other way around, >=, however that was indeed the problem, thank you!

Comment: @Marcin are you sure? You already have two conditions `> = / 2`, why you compare again the same variables (A and B) using the same operator?, this would be redundant.

Comment: I'm trying to find neighbors of a field(A,B) on a grid numbered from 1 to height vertically and 1 to width horizontally, therefore I want x to be >= 1 and <= height, and y to be >=1 and <= width.

Edit: Actually =< is perfectly fine, I'm sorry I misread that.

Comment: That's right, you want A in the range of 1 to Height, so should be `A >= 1` and `A =< Height`.